# Robumeta package - error when fitting a model with an interaction [R, Robumeta, meta-aanlysis]

Tags: r

I am meta-analyzing using the 'robumeta' package.
When I fit a model with an interaction, sometime I receive an error and could not analyze.

```
res2 <- robu (yi ~  fix1 * fix2,
             data = dat, studynum = study, 
var.eff.size = vi, modelweights = "CORR", 
rho = 0.8, small = T)
```

> Error in solve.default(sumXWX) :    Lapack routine dgesv: system is
>   exactly singular: U[9,9] = 0

How can I cope with this? Thank you.

Comment: The matrix is not invertible, and double check that you dont have any NAs. It is hard to say what is going on without seeing the data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @AdamWarner. I double-checked my dataset and found out that few ESs for one level of `fix1`. When I excluded these ESs for the level from the dataset, I can analyze the interaction! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @AdmWarner, in order to deepen my understanding about statistics, could you explain what do you mean by 'The matrix is not invertible'?Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69442/linear-regression-and-non-invertibility is good explanation

Comment: Thank you for the URL, @AdamWarner! As a novice R user and non-native English speaker, the discussion seems to require more time to completely understand for me. I will read the discussion while googling it again. Thank you for providing me this opportunity to learn. I appreciate it.